# How the resonance width can change depending on the different wave 1S, 2S, 3S etc ?

Tags: particle-physics

This is a [picture](https://www.classe.cornell.edu/public/lab-info/upsilon.html) of a Upsilon system. The thing I'm wondering is that energy width $\Gamma$  for forth one (4S) wave is very different than the first three. 
[image]

I know there is a formula which explains the relation between cross-section and energy width $\Gamma$ but i don't understand how this graph can be explained  using the formula:

$$\sigma (E) = \frac{2 J +1 }{(2S_1+1)(2S_2 +1)} \frac{4 \pi}{K^2} \frac{\Gamma^2 /4 }{(E-E_0)^2+ \Gamma^2 /4} B_{in} B_{out}$$

More precisely, How the resonance width can change depending on the different wave 1S, 2S, 3S etc ?

Any details answer will much appreciated.

Comment: If you take a piece of paper and draw the full width at half maximum, you will see that increasing in masses have an increasing width, the last one since it has a smaller crossection is the more obvious. This  would show in the Γ if you fitted a breit wigner  for each resonance.

Comment: correction:The last one since it has an extra decay channel decays faster ( the narrower the resonance the larger the lifetime

Comment: I get it a bit bit  but i want something more rigorous. Could  you please elaborate a bit  in mathematical and with Feynman diagram if possible?

Comment: the link you give above *has* the feynman diagrams.  Have a look at this to see the complexity of what  your are asking.https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.0967